# Do all servers have operating systems?

Tags: operating-system, server, server-application

Do all servers have operating systems?

Can you run applications on any kind of server?

What is an example of an application that can be run on a server?

Believe it or not, I have searched for weeks on Google for answers to these questions, and have come up with nothing. If you can answer any of these I will send good vibes over your way!

Comment: You need to ask yourself what is an operating-system and why does it needed at all (regardless of desktop or server environment). Once you'll clear that up, the answer will be clear. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system

Comment: Well put. That answers my first two questions. Care to take a shot at the last one? Can you name any one application that an be installed on a server?

Comment: The website you're currently browsing (StackOverflow) is an example of a (web) application that is hosted on a server. Servers can be used to run many types of applications (web server, database server etc). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server

Comment: There are servers in which the application and the operating system are the same. They are becoming less common but they do exists.

Answer (score 0):

If it did not have an operating system it would just simply be a box of hardware that did... nothing.
You need an operating system for almost everything- calculators have them,tvs,phones,car park meters,digital cameras and a lot more.
An operating system is what controls the device and makes and delivers the commands which the processor will process and etc.
Maybe you should read up about operating systems as they are quite fascinating in one way :)